# Approximating the derivative at $~x=1~$ given $~f(1), ~f(0.8)~$

Tags: numerical-methods

Given that $f(0.8)=2.2255, f(1.0)=2.7183, \int_{0.8}^{1.0}f(x)e^{-x}dx=0.2$,

I need to find an approximation of $f'(1.0)$ using a method with error of degree $~2~$.

I'm studying for a test and I've seen many questions like this one. My guessing is that I should use **Central Difference** as this is the only method of error of degree $~2~$ that I studied, though I don't know how to to proceed really.

I'd like to get some intuition on how to approach such questions.

Comment: Yes, only $f(x+h)$ at the numerator, not the derivative. So how do you suggest to approach this?

Comment: @Sorry, I screwed up, I meant $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$. I am afraid you cannot do it that way. The value of the integral has to be used somewhere. What results do you know regarding that? (I don't know any myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 pieces of data, thus you can compute an approximating function with 3 parameters, for ease of application take the product of a quadratic polynomial with the exponential function, $p(x)=e^x(ax^2+bx+c)$. Then you get the 3 equations
\begin{align}
e^{0.8}(a0.8^2+b0.8+c)&=2.2255\\
e^1(a+b+c)&=2.7183\\
\frac{a}3(1-0.8^3)+\frac{b}2(1-0.8^2)+c(1-0.8)&=0.2
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
0.64a+0.8b+c&=1\\
a+b+c&=1\\
0.81333a+0.9b+c&=1
\end{align}

Solve this and then compute $p'(1)=e^1(3a+2b+c)$.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Could you explain though why this is an approximating function? And why is the error of degree 2?

Comment: You probably can't with any certainty. The function $f$ could be any of $e^x[1+(x-0.8)(x-0.9)(1-x)g((x-0.8)(1-x))]$, one would have to assume that $f$ is nice, slowly changing in all derivatives, to restrict the size of $g$. After that, the factor before $g$ leads to a quadratic term in the derivative.